# lasinfo - Codec can't decode byte

Tags: command-line, lastools, unicodedecodeerror

I am adding lidar info into qgis, and when I run lasinfo I get the errors listed below. I have tried redownloading the data but the same errors always come back

Errors
Parameters
verbose False
run new 64 bit executable   False
open LAStools GUI   False
input LAS/LAZ file  E:/National LIDAR programme DSM 2019/Unzipped raw files/DSM_ST6570_P_10631_20190117_20190117.tif
compute density False
repair bounding box False
repair counters False
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
additional command line parameter(s)
Error
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users/rhjon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\LAStools\lasinfo.py", line 95, in processAlgorithm LAStoolsUtils.runLAStools(commands, feedback) File "C:\Users/rhjon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\LAStoolsUtils.py", line 61, in runLAStools feedback.pushConsoleInfo(output.decode("utf-8")) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 127: invalid start byte

Parameters
verbose False
run new 64 bit executable   False
open LAStools GUI   False
input LAS/LAZ file  E:/National LIDAR programme DSM 2019/Unzipped raw files/DSM_ST7555_P_10652_20181210_20190109.tif
compute density False
repair bounding box False
repair counters False
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
additional command line parameter(s)
Error
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users/rhjon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\LAStools\lasinfo.py", line 95, in processAlgorithm LAStoolsUtils.runLAStools(commands, feedback) File "C:\Users/rhjon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\LAStoolsUtils.py", line 61, in runLAStools feedback.pushConsoleInfo(output.decode("utf-8")) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 127: invalid continuation byte

Parameters
verbose False
run new 64 bit executable   False
open LAStools GUI   False
input LAS/LAZ file  E:/National LIDAR programme DSM 2019/Unzipped raw files/DSM_ST7560_P_10652_20181210_20190109.tif
compute density False
repair bounding box False
repair counters False
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
histogram   0
bin size    1.0
additional command line parameter(s)
Error
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users/rhjon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\LAStools\lasinfo.py", line 95, in processAlgorithm LAStoolsUtils.runLAStools(commands, feedback) File "C:\Users/rhjon/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\LAStoolsUtils.py", line 61, in runLAStools feedback.pushConsoleInfo(output.decode("utf-8")) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdc in position 229: invalid continuation byte

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to run lasinfo with TIFF files as input?  That's not a supported format for lasinfo

Comment: QGIS will easily accept a tif file, so why are you trying to do something or other with LASTools? If you really want a las/laz file, use LASTools "demzip" to convert tif to laz. Your question could use more clarity. What do you want to do?

Comment: The files are mainly TIFF, that's the format they were downloaded from DEFRA.  I am trying to process them so they don't liik like a blurred layer of no data to something I can revies and use. I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.geodose.com/2020/01/tutorial-lidar-data-processing-lastools-qgis.html

Comment: That link deals with LAS files and is NOT applicable to Tiff files. Drag-n-Drop your Tiff files into QGIS.

Comment: How am i meant to process them though?

Comment: LASTools is what i've always used in the past to process lidar results to show, or not show in some cases, the information i want to get from them

Comment: LAS format is LiDAR. Tiff format is not LiDAR; it is a derivative product. Still trying to understand what you want to do. Please explain in detail what you mean by "process lidar results".

Comment: It looks like black, grey and white smudge.  No clarity, no clear definition of anything at all